# Using multiple instances of a single array adapter in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I'm working on a newsreader, and I have two main activites, main and stories.  Main calls asynctask and gets all the rss feeds, and then displays headlines when it's complete.  Stories displays articles from specific feeds.  There is a navbar in main that calls stories.

My downloaded and parsed articles are in a hashmap of arraylists of the feeds. I only have one adapter class, arrayAdapter. Everything works fine, and I create separate instances of arrayAdapter each time I create a new listview, but the problem is when I go back from stories to main and click on anything in the list, particularly when there are fewer items in stories then the headlines in main, it crashes with:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099654, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class package.package.ArticleListAdapter)]

I think my error is coming from the adapters not acting like separate instances, despite the fact that I think I've made them as separate.  I looked around for help with this, but most of what I saw was about people changing their data from a background thread, not inside a separate activity.

Unfortunately, this code is paraphrased, partially for readability, and partially because I'm writing it for someone else, closed source yadda yadda...

```
class main{  
  public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArticleHolder>> allArticles;  
  public ArticleListAdapter ArtListAdapter;  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     allArticles = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArticleHolder>>();
     myApp appstate = (myApp)getApplicationContext();  
     appState.setParsedArticles(allArticles); //Added this for universal availability of the articles
     //download things  
     //background.execute();  
     //...  

  }  

 private class downloader extends Asynctask ...{  
 ...  
 onPostExecute(){
    ArticleListAdapter = new ArticleListAdapter(context c, list_item L, allArticles.get(1));
    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView1.setAdapter(ArtListAdapter);
   }
 }


class stories{  
  public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArticleHolder>> allArticles;  
  public ArticleListAdapter ArtListAdapter;  

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    myApp appstate = (myApp)getApplicationContext();
    allArticles = appState.getParsedArticles();
    //set layout
    //get article to display from Bundle extras
    ListView LV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArtListAdapter = new ArticleListAdapter(StoriesScreenActivity.this, R.layout.article_list_item, allCleanArticles.get(buttonFeedNum));
    LV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    LV.setAdapter(ArtListAdapter);
    }
}
```

Code for the adapter as follows and is exact:

```
public class ArticleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArticleHolder>{
    private static ArrayList<ArticleHolder> ArticleList;
    private Context context; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ArticleListAdapter(Context pcontext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ArticleHolder> results) {
        super(pcontext, layoutResourceId, results);
        context = pcontext;
        ArticleList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtMain = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.txtblurb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.pic_view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtMain.setText(ArticleList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtblurb.setText(ArticleList.get(position).getMainText());
        holder.pic_view.setContentDescription(context.getString(R.string.GenImgDesc));
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.pic_view, ArticleList.get(position).getPicName(),R.drawable.ic_placeholder);

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ArticleList.size();
    }

    public ArticleHolder getItem(int position) {
        return ArticleList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtMain;
        TextView txtblurb;
        ImageView pic_view;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help, I'm really stuck.
Also, many thanks and props to koush and Jwsonic on Github for their work on UrlImageViewer.  It's awesome.

Edit:
Here's my AsyncTask.doInBackground().  Sorry I took so long, I was out of town for a while without my computer.  Thanks again for all your help.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    boolean succeeded = false;
    String downloadPath = null;

    for(Integer num: feedArray){
        downloadPath = "example.com/rss/"+Integer.toString(num);
        doSax(downloadPath, num);
    }
    for(Integer num: feedArray){
        currentDirtyFeedArticles = allDirtyArticles.get(num);
        for(ArticleHolder dirtyArticle: currentDirtyFeedArticles){
            dirtyArticle.setTitle(textCleaner(dirtyArticle.getTitle()));

            //some text cleaning to make it look pretty

            }
        }
        succeeded = true;
        return succeeded;
}
```

Alright, so I took Jedi_warriors advice and attempted to add the notifyDataSetChanged(), but I couldn't figure it how to get it to mesh with my custom adapter.  It put me on the right path though, as I realized the listview on the homescreen wasn't getting updated when I returned to it.  This led me to look into having an onResume method, and after some trial and error, I ended up calling the code to associate the view with adapter in onResume.  The trick here was that the app crashed when it opened because that code wasn't ready, so I prevented the code in onResume from running until after the app was ready to go.  As far as I can tell, that seems to have fixed the problem.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Post your AsyncTask.doInBackground() method would helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in asynctask:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

cause this has acces of Ui .
And For ListView use listview.notifyDataSetChanged();

hope this helps

Comment: Try This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-dataAndroid/) and This [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/newsdroid-rss-reader)